# Code that takes student's names and scores and sorts them in order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am writing a code that takes a teachers class size and then creates an array that holds their names and scores. The idea is to have it so the code sorts them by their scores (Not their name). My issue is that I can't seem to get the score part of the data to be in double. Basically, the code only takes in int inputs.

I want the code to do this when I'm done.

How many students in your class? 6

1. Name: Tom Smith

   Score: 82.5
2. Name: Mary Smith

   Score: 92.5
3. Name: Alice Falls

   Score: 61
4. Name: Linda Newson

   Score: 73
5. Name: Jack Turner

   Score: 89.3
6. Name: George Brown

   Score: 52

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class FinalJamesVincent {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter the number of students: ");
       int numofstudents = input.nextInt();
       String[] names = new String[numofstudents];
       double[] array = new double[numofstudents];
       for(int i = 0; i < numofstudents; i++) {
           System.out.print("Name: ");
           names[i] = input.next();
           System.out.print("Score: ");
           array[i] = input.nextInt();
       }
       selectionSort(names, array);
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
   }
   public static void selectionSort(String[] names, double[] array) {
       for(int i = array.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
           String temp;
           double currentMax = array[0];
           int currentMaxIndex = 0;
           for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
              if (currentMax > array[j]) {
                  currentMax = array[j];
                  currentMaxIndex = j;
              }
           }       
              if (currentMaxIndex != i) {
                  temp = names[currentMaxIndex];
                  names[currentMaxIndex] = names[i];
                  names[i] = temp;
                  array[currentMaxIndex] = array[i];
                  array[i] = currentMax;
              }
       }       
   }
}
```

Comment: Use `nextDouble` instead of `nextInt` to get a `double` instead of an `int`.

Comment: I understand if you are a beginner, but the better approach to this would be to make a `Student` class. And store them into a `Student[]` that you can sort.

Answer (score 3):

```
array[i] = input.nextInt();
```

Whereas `nextInt()` parses the input into an integer, to take a `double` input, you should use `input.nextDouble()`.

Replace it with `array[i] = input.nextDouble();` That would make it perfect.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be simple.